# How to use the Clink lua api?

Tags: lua, autocomplete

As far as I can tell, Clink (http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) doesn't provide any documentation on how to use the lua API it mentions.

I've looked at the content of the clink.lua file in the installation directory and I can sort of see how it works, but I'm wondering how I can write my own lua files to add new argument autocompletions (I don't want to edit clink.lua directly for risk of breaking existing functionality) and have Clink detect and use my files.

Has anyone had any luck playing around with this in the past?

Comment: There's one actively updated fork at https://github.com/chrisant996/clink/, see its document at https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [many people have the same question](https://github.com/vladimir-kotikov/clink-completions/issues/48).

The most comprehensive manual I have found is [this document](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/298113a61272afa3f646a912c97e2ce34da67597/docs/clink.md#file-locations), which is in git, but not in master. It is well-written and covers a lot.

Brief summary:

**File Location**

In clink v0.4.6, the installation has a `profile/` directory. After putting the lua completion files in that directory they were picked up when starting a new process or refreshing with Ctl-Q.

The document talks about `c:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data` (for XP) and `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local` (Vista onwards). I tried this with clink-1.0.0a1.823d84 but have not (yet) been able to get this to work.

**Syntax**

Here is an example of a simple parser for the command foobar;

```lua
my_parser = clink.arg.new_parser()
my_parser:set_flags("-foo", "-bar")
my_parser:set_arguments(
    { "hello", "hi" },     -- first position
    { "world", "wombles" } -- second position
)
clink.arg.register_parser("foobar", my_parser)
```

In the first position (after `foobar`) clink will suggest `hello` or `hi`.
After that, in the second position (after `foobar hello` or `foobar hi`), clink will suggest `world` or `wombles`.
The flags are position independent.

Instead of calling `set_flags` and `set_arguments`, you can also use this compact syntax:

```lua
some_parser = clink.arg.new_parser(
    { "arg1-1", "arg1-2" },
    { "arg2-1", "arg2-2" },
    "-flag1", "-flag2"
)
```

**Advanced Syntax**

Parsers can be nested, which is useful for flags that take a limited number of valid values.

Clink allows you to link parsers using Lua's `..` concatenation operator. For example:

```lua
local parser = clink.arg.new_parser
local my_parser = parser(
    "-s" .. parser({"ruby", "webpi", "cygwin", "windowsfeatures", "python"}),
    "--source" .. parser({"ruby", "webpi", "cygwin", "windowsfeatures", "python"}),
    "--version",
clink.arg.register_parser("mycommand", my_parser)
```

This can also be used to implement completion for "command suites" (a command with subcommands). For example:

```lua
local parser = clink.arg.new_parser
local git_parser = parser(
    {
        "add" .. parser({}, -- empty {}: don't suggest any positional args
            "-n", "--dry-run",
            "-v", "--verbose",
            "-f", "--force",
            "-i", "--interactive",
            "-A", "--all",
            "--refresh"
            ),
        "commit" .. parser(
            "-a", "--all",
            "-m", "--message=",
            "-e", "--edit",
            "--amend",
            "-u", "--untracked-files", "--untracked-files=", -- .. parser({"no", "normal", "all"}),
            "-v", "--verbose",
            "-q", "--quiet",
            "--"
        ),
        "remote"..parser({
            "add" ..parser(
                "-t"..parser({branches}), -- defined elsewhere
                "-m",
                "-f",
                "--mirror",
                "--tags", "--no-tags"
            ),
            "rename"..parser({remotes}),
            "remove"..parser({remotes}),
            "rm"..parser({remotes}),
            "set-head"..parser({remotes}, {branches},
                "-a", "--auto",
                "-d", "--delete"
            ),
            "set-branches"..parser("--add", {remotes}, {branches}),
            "set-url"..parser(
                "--add"..parser("--push", {remotes}),
                "--delete"..parser("--push", {remotes})
            ),
            "get-url"..parser({remotes}, "--push", "--all"),
            "show"..parser("-n", {remotes}),
            "prune"..parser("-n", "--dry-run", {remotes}),
            "update"..parser({remotes}, "-p", "--prune")
            }, "-v", "--verbose"),
    },
    "--version",
    "--help",
    "-c",
    "--git-dir",
)

clink.arg.register_parser("git", git_parser)
```

This is an abbreviated version of Vladimir Kotikov's [git.lua](https://github.com/vladimir-kotikov/clink-completions/blob/master/git.lua) completion script. See the original for the full source.

**Pre-built CLink Completions**

Vladimir Kotikov has created a very nice collection of [clink-completion scripts](https://github.com/vladimir-kotikov/clink-completions) for many common commands. He also [pointed out](https://github.com/vladimir-kotikov/clink-completions/issues/48#issuecomment-396841579) the hidden clink manual I mentioned earlier. Don't forget to leave his GitHub project a star! :-)